# Selecting annotation by color to correct Annotation Class using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select, color, annotation, arcgis-10.6

I have some municipal data that was converted into a GIS and all of the address numbers were coded as dimensions in the annotation feature class. There is an annotation class for address, but none of the addresses are of that type. However, all of the addresses are displayed on the maps in a particular color (Mars Red/255 0 0), which makes me think there is a way to select these address numbers.

I have found that there is an arcpy tool called Select Features by Symbol Color (SelectFeaturesBySymbolColor_production) but I do not have the production mapping extension available.

Is there a way to make this selection using the mapping module, perhaps? Or an open source solution? Or if I could make a definition query for those it would be easy to quickly select them.

I'm using ArcMap 10.6